# Efficient Insert Query Against Multiple Tables in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing an insert in MySQL against multiple tables than a separate insert query for each record in each table.  I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
  (t1c1, t1c2, t1c3), table2 (t2c1, t2c2, t2c3) 
VALUES
  ('t1c1', 't1c2', 't1c3', 't2c1', 't2c2', 't2c3');
```

The reason for this is that the data is collated on a remote machine and will be doing the insert over the network.

Comment: I dont see a reason for it, MySQL will still need to two different tables for that operation. If you are inserting massive amounts of data the best method is to send compressed CSV file to server and use `LOAD DATA` to insert them to a table with a blazing speed.

Comment: Ok I see your point but you still have the issue of transfering the file across the network then the LOAD DATA. Would it not be more efficient to just have an insert query?

Comment: The query would transfer the data anyway, so the contents of the file are going over the network in any case.

Comment: I understand this but which is more intensive file transfer or insert query? I would think that the cheaper option would be the query and not the file.

Comment: Transferring a 2MB file is the same as sending a 2MB query, why should one of them be more 'intensive'? If you compress the file before sending, it would be an actual gain in favor of the file transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way of doing this in a single step. You will need to perform multiple queries.

Comment: Could I not use a view to link the tables and then insert into the view?

Comment: Not even this is possible, unfortunately. I have been searching for this feature myself for a very long time :/

Answer (score 0):

You could insert into one table first, then into the second one from the first table:

```
INSERT INTO table1 ....
VALUES(....

INSERT INTO table2(....
SELECT ...
FROM table1 
WHERE ....
```

Comment: Would this not mean a duplication of data between the tables? The program on the remote machine is not a database and both tables are on the remote database server.